# How can I open an external website in new tab and press button on it from .net MVC application?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, model-view-controller

I was able to do this job using selenium Webdriver. But I can't use it as it requires external executable.  I want this solution to be done in C# or Javascript. Attaching the code I implemented using selenium C#.

```
'''
    IWebDriver m_driver;
    m_driver = new ChromeDriver();
    m_driver.Url = "/sample_url";
    link = m_driver.FindElement(By.Id("accept"));
    link.Click();
'''
```

Comment: Do you "own" both pages?

Comment: No. I just own the first one.

Comment: I don't believe this will be possible without some externam app / script (extension)

Comment: Thank you for information. Can u suggest any extension I can use? I do have permission to scrap website from site owner.